# Google Analytics Not listing all web properties

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When using google analytics core reporting api i am unable to get all properties of an account some properties are missing and all are those which has no view in analytics dashboard of google
here is my code

```
$data=[];$id = "abc1234";
    $properties = $this->analytics->management_webproperties
        ->listManagementWebproperties("~all")->getItems();
    foreach ($properties as $user) {
        $data[$user->getId()] = ['id' => $user->getId(), 'name' => $user->getName()];
    }
    return collect(array_values($data));
```

please tell me if i miss something or not using latest version of api i am using V4.
please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APIs you are using are for the **Google Analytics Universal** version, while the properties that 'don't have a view' are from **Google Analytics 4** (the new Google Analytics, ex App+Web).

This version of Google Analytics offers its API specifications (`Analytics Data API`), you can see here an early preview version: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

Comment: means i need to change code to implement GA4 accounts

Comment: Yes, whereas the APIs for GA4 are new and subject to change.

Comment: can you suggest for php laravel what third party can i use for GA4 implementation

Comment: for the moment everything is very unripe, I don't think there are optimal solutions to suggest yet

Comment: i check this library https://packagist.org/packages/google/analytics-admin i am able to get GA4 properties but don't know how can i get metrics data